# Dapper - How to create class instance by column value?

Tags: c#, .net, dapper

How to instantiate class by specific column value with Dapper?

Let's say we have table 'items' with columns: ID, Type, Name...

And, when Type is equal to "Burger", class Burger should be instantiated, when Type is "Sandwich", class Sandwich should be instantiated.

First approach that comes to my mind is to execute query for every type, for example:

```
var sandwiches = conn.Query<Sandwich>("SELECT * FROM items WHERE Type = 'Sandwich'");
var burgers = conn.Query<Burger>("SELECT * FROM items WHERE Type = 'Burger'");
```

But this approach is expensive because we will have as many queries as number of item types.
Can we do the same job with single query? (Select all rows and create instances based on column value)

Comment: I think you are looking at this from the wrong point of view. Instead of looking at how have a method that do every query , you should look at your domain model and build for each domain model a specific class for that model that is focused on the database layer aspect of things. So for example, if you have Burger class then have a BurgerDB class that makes all the jobs required to search, save, update and delete Burger objects.

Comment: Thank you for answer, Steve!
I undestand you, but im talking about only loading all items from db, trying to load them all with single query and instantiate them with dapper based on Type column. All item classes have same properties, all of them inherit same base class.
I thought it would be better approach if i have different classes instead of one big class with Type property and many swich statements inside nearly all methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use method's generic argument to get type

```
public class ItemsRepository
{
    private const string Query = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE Type = @Type";
    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetItemsBasedOnTypeAsync<T>()
    {
        await using var connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LOCAL);Initial Catalog=LinqPadTest;Integrated Security=True;");
        await connection.OpenAsync();
        var parameters = new { Type = nameof(T) };
        return connection.Query<T>(Query, parameters);
    }
}
```

now you can call method for any items type

```
var itemsRepository = new ItemsRepository();
var sandwiches = await itemsRepository.GetItemsBasedOnTypeAsync<Sandwich>();
var burgers = await itemsRepository.GetItemsBasedOnTypeAsync<Burger>();
```

V2(select all items):
use can do something like this, or cast to base interface if exists.

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
    public int Property2 { get; set; }
}

public class Sandwich
{
    public Sandwich(Item item)
    {
        Id = item.Id;
        Property1 = item.Property1;
        Property2 = item.Property2;
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
    public int Property2 { get; set; }
}

public class Burger
{
    public Burger(Item item)
    {
        Id = item.Id;
        Property1 = item.Property1;
        Property2 = item.Property2;
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
    public int Property2 { get; set; }
}

public class ItemsRepository
{
    private const string Query = "SELECT * FROM items";
    public async Task<IEnumerable<object>> GetItemsBasedOnTypeAsync()
    {
        await using var connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LOCAL);Initial Catalog=LinqPadTest;Integrated Security=True;");
        await connection.OpenAsync();
        var items =  connection.Query<Item>(Query);
        var objects = items.Select(Create)
            .ToList();
        return objects;
    }

    private object? Create(Item item) =>
        Assembly
            .GetExecutingAssembly()
            .CreateInstance(item.Type,true,BindingFlags.Public,null,
                new object[]{item},
                CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture, null);
}
```

Comment: Yep, but i asked if it's possible to execute one query and then instantiate classes based on  Type column for every row.

Your answer is definitely better approach than mine, but it will execute query for every item type.

Comment: just added second solution to my comment, if you want to get each type in different list, maybe you have to write switch statement

Answer (score 0):

A class could have a generic method that could do what you want:

```
public class Query
{
    public IEnumerable<T> GenericQuery<T>(string query) 
    {
        using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LOCAL);Initial Catalog=LinqPadTest;Integrated Security=True;"))
        {
            cnn.Open();
            return cnn.Query<T>(query);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can call it in this way

```
void Main()
{
    var q = new Query();
    var sandwiches = q.GenericQuery<Sandwich>("SELECT * FROM items WHERE Type = 'Sandwich'");
    var burgers = q.GenericQuery<Burger>("SELECT * FROM items WHERE Type = 'Burger'");
}
```